# Click Multiple Value Tabbed Button Only If It Contains Buy Or Sell

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click a `tabbed button` if it is set to `Buy or Sell`.

Basically detect if the flag `Buy or Sell` is set in the tabbed button.

The BUY Sell Tabbed Button is on URL [Kraken](https://trade.kraken.com/charts/KRAKEN:BTC-USDT)

Basically detect if `disabled="">Buy<` says Buy, if so then click the button

Or if `disabled="">Sell<` says Sell, if so then click the button.

When clicking Buy the code changes to :

```
<button class="_1_R9vNUDdcou2Z7JyNUxJO _2L9SQFRN3bCg-05kS6dcFn" tabindex="0" disabled="">Buy</button>
<button class="_1_R9vNUDdcou2Z7JyNUxJO" tabindex="0">Sell</button>
```

Code I'm using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='_1_R9vNUDdcou2Z7JyNUxJO']").click()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
#locate the button
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='_1_R9vNUDdcou2Z7JyNUxJO']")

#get button text
button_text=button.text

#find attribute(disabled) value for the button
button_disabled=button.get_attribute("disabled")

#if button text=Buy or Sell and button disabled value="" click the button
if (button_text=='Sell' and button_disabled=="") or (button_text=='Buy' and button_disabled==""):
   button.click()
```

Comment: Hi, If you read the entire question, Im trying to detect if disabled="">Sell< then click the button, could you alter your reply to include  if disabled="">Sell< then click the button, Thnx

Comment: Hey, I have edited the code to check for the attribute value as well. Let me know if it works for you!!